# How can I resize my map according to the device width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, mapbox

I created a little website for the upcoming football world cup. The website contains a map (provided by mapbox), which is the most important element in my website, so it is the background of the website. The width is set to 100%. Now I would like to resize the map according to the device (tablet, phone), so that the map and the whole website looks similar on each device.

Here is a code snippet from my javascript:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'hashtagwinti.i72di96c', { 
zoomControl: false, 
maxZoom: 10, 
minZoom: 2, 
} )
.setView([-8, -50], 4); 
L.control.scale({position: 'bottomleft', metric: true, imperial:false}).addTo(map);
map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(brazil).addTo(map);
```

Here is my css of my body and the map:

```
body { 
margin:0; 
padding:0; 
width:auto% !important;
height: auto% !important;
}

#map { 
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
bottom:0;
width:100%;
```

Now I'd like that on every device the map view is the same. At the moment the zoom level  doesn't change (the map view isn't the same) if you go on the website from for example the an iPhone.

any ideas?

(if already looked for a solution on the mapbox API, but I didn't found a solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell Mapbox which screen size you want to adjust for with a media query-type call in and to do something different for that size with an if/else statement.

For example, to set a zoom level for a phone screen size less than 420px it'd be something like this:

```
var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 420px)" );

if (mq.matches){
    var map = new L.mapbox.map('map', 'hashtagwinti.i72di96c').setView([-8, -50], 4); //set map zoom level for desktop size
} else {
    var map = new L.mapbox.map('map', 'hashtagwinti.i72di96c').setView([-8, -50], 3); //set map zoom level for mobile size
};
```

You can set other things too like map center, markers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've found using `map.invalidateSize();` the simplest solution to adjust the map size based on the size of the browser window or parent container.

Here is some more information about invalidateSize on MapBox's website: https://www.mapbox.com/help/why-map-cropped-hidden-shown/